# linker command failed with exit code 1 (while importing and compiling a new project)

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x-2.x

I have imported a project of cocos2dx, whenever i tried to run the project it shows me following error.

```
ld: library not found for -lcocos2d libraries
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I dont know what to do.

Comment: Xcode build settings: *Library Search Path*.

Comment: @trojanfoe in 'Xcode build setting: Library Search Path' it is blank, so how can i add library path into it.

Comment: Well it depends where cocos2d is located.  If it's a sibling to the xcode project then something like `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../cocos2d` or some such.  I think normally you are supposed to include the cocos2d sources as part of your projects, perhaps as a separate static library target.  You don't provide enough information to answer definitively, however.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am developing the cocos2dx project in that i have imported one sample project and i got the error as specified above.